# Multiple identical writes to the same memory

Tags: glsl, vulkan

Can I have multiple geometry shader invocations (in a single rendering command) write **the exact same value** to the **same SSBO memory location** without any synchronization. or will this result in Undefined Behavior? If not, will the result be well defined? (May I safely assume the result will be consistent among different platforms?)

The SSBO will then be read by a different shader in a subsequent rendering command, after the required buffer pipeline barrier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vulkan memory model is [quite clear](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap44.html#memory-model-access-data-race):

> Let X and Y be operations that access overlapping sets of memory locations M, where X != Y, and at least one of X and Y is a write, and X and Y are not mutually-ordered atomic operations. If there does not exist a location-ordered relation between X and Y for each location in M, then there is a data race.
>
> Applications **must** ensure that no data races occur during the execution of their application.

Emphasis *not* added. When the standard says "Applications **must** do X" that means "if the application doesn't do X, then UB results".

Two non-atomic writes with no appropriate synchronization between them is a data race and therefore represents undefined behavior. This is without regard to the *value* of those writes. Note that X and Y are *operations*, so when it says, "where X != Y", it's not talking about the value of those operations. It's saying where they are *different* operations.

Comment: Thanks, I have read the specs, I just wanted to be sure about the "if the application doesn't do X, then UB results" part